# Writing the transformation matrix for the following in terms of Kronecker products of elementary 2-qubit gates

Tags: quantum-gate, mathematics, linear-algebra, terminology-and-notation

I have a set of transformations that transforms $|11001\rangle\to |10101\rangle$ which is basically keeping the leftmost qubit as it is and then it is just the CNOT between the successive qubits, I have done the circuit construction for this with the steps with the register $|abcde\rangle$
$$1.~~  \operatorname{CNOT}|d,e\rangle$$
$$2.~~  \operatorname{CNOT}|c,d\rangle$$
$$3.~~  \operatorname{CNOT}|b,c\rangle$$
$$4.~~  \operatorname{CNOT}|a,b\rangle$$
after these transformations, we get the desired results, but how do I write this whole transformation in Dirac notation or matrix notation. I have figured it myself can somebody just check 
for the  $$1.   A=\mathrm{kron}(\mathrm{kron}(\mathrm{kron}(I_2,I_2),I_2),U)$$
         $$2.   B=\mathrm{kron}(\mathrm{kron}(\mathrm{kron}(I_2,I_2),U),I_2)$$
         $$3.   C=\mathrm{kron}(\mathrm{kron}(\mathrm{kron}(I_2,U),I_2),I_2)$$
         $$4.   D=\mathrm{kron}(\mathrm{kron}(\mathrm{kron}(U,I_2),I_2),I_2)$$
where $$U=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
The last step is just to multiply all these matrix so final transformation matrix is $$U_f=ABCD$$
I have the circuit representation for $8$-qubits as [image]

Since this is product of unitary of transformations, i need $6$ unitary matrices for this. The first of these matrices say $U_1$ that i calculated shoyld be $$ U_1= I^6\otimes \lbrace{|0\rangle \langle 0|\otimes I+|1\rangle \langle 1|\otimes X\rbrace }$$ similarly for the other $5$ matrices just the identity matrix size keeps changing. Is my inference correct, can somebody help?

Comment: I expected some sort of an answer atleast

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Only thing you need 7 unitaries for 8 qubits not 6. And the identity keeps on changing size but you keep on adding identity to the right. In general $U_j = I^{\otimes (7-j)}\otimes CNOT \otimes I^{\otimes(j-1)}$ . $j$ goes from 1 to 7. Then your full unitary would be $U_7U_6\cdots U_1$

Comment: Also $U_f $ for 5 qubit scenario in the question would be $U_f = DCBA$

Comment: why should it be DCBA?

Comment: Your circuit requires $A$ to be applied first.

Comment: okay i see it because the operations on qubits $d$ and $e$ is applied first

Comment: Representing this using Recursion would be so much easier